# find value in column and based on it create a new dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a variable in the following format `fg = 2017-20`. It's a string. And also I have a dataframe:

```
  flag     №
2017-18   389
2017-19   390
2017-20   391
2017-21   392
2017-22   393
2017-23   394
...
```

I need to find this value (`fg`) in the column `"flag"` and select the appropriate value (in the example it will be `391`) in the column `"№"`. Then create new dataframe, in which there will also be a column `"№"`. Add this value to this dataframe and iterate 53 times. The result should look like this:

```
 №_new
  391
  392
  393
  394
  395
  ...
  442
  443
  444
```

It does not look difficult, but I can not find anything suitable based on other issues. Can someone advise anything, please?

Comment: Why 53 times? Is it length of `DataFrame` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for filtering, then convert one item `Series` to scalar by convert to numpy array by [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.values.html) and select first value by `[0]`.

Last create new `DataFrame` with [`numpy.arange`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html).

```
fg = '2017-20'
val = df.loc[df['flag'] == fg, '№'].values[0]
print (val)
391

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'№_new':np.arange(val, val+53)})
print (df1)
    №_new
0     391
1     392
2     393
3     394
4     395
5     396
6     397
7     398
8     399
9     400
10    401
11    402
..
..
```

Comment: I think, OP meant, more like `np.arange(val, val+53)`? Not very sure tho.